# Texture coordinates

Tags: texture, coordinates

Consider the square shown below on the left, which has been textured with the image shown on the right. What are the texture coordinates of the vertices a, b, c, and d?

Does anyone know how to answer this?

[image: Question]

Comment: This is like that SAT question, how many revolutions does a circle with 1/3 the radius of a larger circle make around the larger circle.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot leave a comment because I do not have enough reputation points.

You could rotate the UV coordinates by pi/4.0. You'll also have to scale by sqrt(2.0).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the centre of the star has texture coordinates $[0.5, 0.5]$ then $a,b,c,d$ all have the same texture coordinate $[0.5, 0.5]$.

Answer (score 0):

Also guessing the center of the star is [0.5, 0.5] so

```
a = [-0.5+x, 0.5+y] 
b = [0.5+x, 1.5+y] 
c = [1.5+x, 0.5+y] 
d = [0.5+x, -0.5+y]
```

$ \forall x, y \in \mathbb{Z} $